# Search inside gitlab jobs logs

Tags: gitlab

Many times, I have an image hash which I know was published in one of the pipelines in my gitlab project. I would like to find what pipeline created it.

Is there an easy way to grep logs of all/some jobs/pipelines in gitlab?